# Asp.Net core 2 form validation on html <select> element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Simple asp.net core 2 web app where I post a form. On validation errors, ModelState is filled with error details. Html `<input>` elements who are related to field with error are rendered with css class `input-validation-error`. Html `<select>` elements don't have the same beahviour, the `input-validation-error` css class is not added. Is there some way to have css error class added to those `<select>` elements ?

Comment: They already *are*. However, you have to have something that will actually trigger a validation error. For a select, that's pretty much just `Required`, and will simply validate that *something* was selected, not necessarily what you want selected.

Comment: Also, if you don't have an empty option, then something is *always* selected, so even `Required` validation will not trigger.